# Change color of labels using clabel (Matlab 2015a)

Tags: matlab, colors, label

I'm able to add the 1rst, 2nd, ..., 5th contours of some data using:

`[c,h] = contour(x,y,data,[1 2 3 4 5],'color','m');`

For coherence I ask to label these contours **in magenta** using the simple:

`clabel(c,h,[1 2 3 4 5],'color','m')`

but no matter what the options are, `clabel` does not take them into account and labels in black.

Is there a trick that I am missing? Exploring the documentation did not help much and I've seen this problem reported a couple times, but with no answer.
It appears that using `clabel` in manual mode allows to choose the color.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1114747) bugreport submitted to Mathworks and download the attached file. This  works for R2014b and R2015a and has been fixed in R2015b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1114747) from [Benoit_11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3352541/benoit-11) as an answer to this issue. Thanks!